# Browser doesn't respect new css settings till drag action is not finished

Tags: javascript, css, ng2-dragula

I have a problem with `ng2-dragula`. I try to use it on mobile device, so I need to stop scrolling when element is dragged. On `ng2-dragula` GitHub users suggest to use `touch-action: none` on element with scroll.

I try to add this property into my `body` element, so I use:

```
        this.dragula$.add(this.dragulaService.drag('GOALS')
            .subscribe(({name, el, source}) => {
                this.document.body.style.touchAction = 'none';
            })
        );
```

When I try to drag element I see in Chrome Inspector that `touch-action: none` is added but it doesn't change browser reaction till I drop element. When I try to drag it again everything work good and `body` is not scrolling anymore. But I want to use also:

```
        this.dragula$.add(this.dragulaService.dragend('GOALS')
            .subscribe(({name, el}) => {
                this.document.body.style.touchAction = 'auto';
            })
        );
```

to restore previous settings after element is drop.

It's any browser settings which prevent new settings till the end of actual drag operation?

Answer (score 0):

I investigate this problem really deep and it look like change class detection in ng2-dragula is only triggered on start event, and if you change any class during a drag&drop process this change has no impact on your actually action.

Finally we can't use class changing to control a drag&drop process. Maybe it can be change in future update of Dragula.